# How to remove 'public' from Laravel URL hosted on child folder?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I have a `Laravel 5.3` project on shared hosting located at the following [address](http://www.mydomain.tld/home/public/).

How to remove the **public** from URL?

Now the same question was asked at [Remove public from URL Laravel 5.3 on shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158002/remove-public-from-url-laravel-5-3-on-shared-hosting) but many answers were asking to move all public content to root domain, but my root domain is already hosting something with `index.php` in it.

Can you please tell me how to do it? All other information is same as the question shared, i.e default `.htaccess` file in public as well as home (laravel installation) folder. Second I am in shared hosting, I cant change `Vhost` or something.

Here is my folder structure inside https://yourdomain.tld/home folder

[image]

Comment: Wait, what? So when you visit `yourdomain.tld/.env` or `yourdomain.tld/composer.json`, you can see all the content?

Comment: Did you rename server.php to index.php at your laravel root directory?

Comment: @Dragonsnap : nope,1st That is located at yourdomain.tld/home/.env  and 2nd)  that has been protected by bit ninja security (i mean its already permission protected but even though if someone tries to access it, that ip is blocked untill the solve captcha)

Comment: @sta : yes I tried doing that as well, so I moved .htaccess at public directory to yourdomain.tld/home directory and also renamed server.php to index.php

Comment: @sta: but  it didnt worked

Comment: Consider this answer; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url

Comment: @ElektaKode : Hey , I have followed this question and I found it working, one issue though, all the urls That is generated in template is still including public in url, and to access them I have to keep another copy of .htaccess in my public folder as well.

Comment: @ElektaKode : if I change the APP_URL=https://yourdomain.tld/home/public in .env file to APP_URL=https://yourdomain.tld/home , it works fine but it breaks CSS and  JS File !

Comment: @TalkisCheapShowmeCode : Or you can just copy `.htaccess` file and `index.php` file from `public` folder to your project root and try your customization on them.

Comment: ok I have moved everything from public folder to project root and customized index.php and its working like charm, but one more doubt! if i removed old public folder, it gave me error that file dont found, so I think that too is needed, and one more question, which uploads folders is being used?

Comment: It is not recommended to remove the public folder because of that you get vulnerable and your database and other application settings that are in .env file in a simple text format gets exposed easily. I recommend you to login to your hosting, go to the path, then append /public. thats it 3 steps and youd be good to go.

Comment: yes I did that, now ever URL that is printed by laraval is consiting of public in between, thats the exact issue

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 3 possible solutions:

1. Since you use vhost instead of localhost, the problem might be the DocumentRoot declaration. I use Xampp, so the path and code will be based on that. In my case, the file that creates vhost is located:

```
C:\Xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
```

The vhost code is this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Xampp/htdocs/mydomain/home/public"
    ServerName mydomain.tld/home
    ErrorLog "logs/mydomain-e1rror.log"
    CustomLog "logs/mydomain-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

BTW, make sure you 127.0.0.1 mydomain.tld in "etc" file if you use a Windows machine.

When you enter [www.mydomain.tld](http://www.mydomain.tld) it should hit the index.php file that is located in public folder.

2. Since you use very old version of Laravel, I suppose you download it from liveserver. When we deploy our app, we make some changes in public/index.php file to tell our app where Laravel is. Look for

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; //
```

I think this is different in your index.php file. BTW, I don't know if this path is different in version 5.3.

3. Your folder structure is incorrect. You might try to compare it with freshly installed Laravel.

Comment: Hey Thanks for suggesting this so 1st thing is where this document root is located in laravel installation folder or in .htaccess?

Comment: C:/Xampp/htdocs/mydomain is Laravel installation path, and I suppose your public folder is there.

Comment: my public folder is at yourdomain.tld/home/public

Comment: Just set DocumentRoot whatever your public folder path. Actually, let me edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: one more clarification, my yourdomain.tld already is hosting some other site (non-laravel), i want my laravel installation at yourdomain.tld/home

Comment: I never install Laravel to path like /home. Try ServerName with and without /home. One should work, if the problem is vhost of course.

Comment: ok one another question :) 
what if I don't have access to vhosts?

Comment: In this case, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I will right away contact IT support of my hosting provider to modify my VHosts settings.

Comment: Wait a minute. vhost means virtual host and it is the host in your computer, not anywhere else. You can't work on Laravel while it's on live server. I'm sure you can, but it's not convenient. So my explanations based on this case: You downloaded the webpage from live server to your computer and you're working on it locally. If this is not true, please explain what.

Comment: no its actually reverse, I developed on local and now hosting on live server.